# Does asp.net ajax needs XML http?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Ajax needs xmlhttp. Does Asp.net ajax, ajaxcontrol toolkits also needs xmlhttp for their smooth running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the browser it will use either the built-in XmlHttpRequest object or an ActiveX control.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is XMLHttpRequest, so in short, yes ASP.Net needs that (or ActiveX for IE).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the browser component that AJAX uses to makes requests to the server.  The AJAX Toolkit, or more specifically any control that gets data from the server, would require it.  However, the way the toolkit runs...I'm not sure if any controls will run with it disabled, as the base set of client scripts expects it to be enabled.

[You can read more about how AJAX utilizes XMLHttpRequest object here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest.asp).